# Ionic 2 animate an image when click

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm using ionic 2+ and trying to animate an image using animate.css. During initial load the image it should use rubberBand animation and everytime on click it should use bounce animation. The rubberBand animation works fine on load but the bounce animation only works once no matter how many times I click. What am I doing wrong?

**html**

```
<img src="/assets/image.png (click)="animate()" [className]="imgClass"/>
```

**typescript**

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.imgClass = "animated rubberBand";
  }

animate() {
    this.imgClass = "";
    this.imgClass = "animated bounce";
  }
```

Comment: your class is not switching back...

Comment: @suraj he doesn't want to switch back to rubberBand, or so it seems. He just wants to re-activate the bounce animation.

Comment: yes, i want the image to bounce everytime the user clicks on it. sorry if it wasn't clear in the question

Answer (score 1):

So I suppose you want to execute the bounce everything the user clicks on the element?

With your current solution, you're setting the `imgClass` within the same function twice. These get executed immediately and won't refresh the class.

A workaround would be to use:

```
animate() {
  this.imgClass = "animated";

  // this will execute async after 100ms
  setTimeout(() => {
     this.imgClass = "animated bounce";
  }, 100);
}
```

I believe this will work.

Comment: thanks it works but is there any other way to force refresh the UI?

Comment: Probably yes, but that I know of? Not really, maybe if your library has a sort of Javascript possibilities which you can use to reload to script itself / replay the animations